# Delphi6 code: A simple hello world app, calling a form2.bpl but hitting a wall

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I am trying to make this main app call my `.bpl`, but not sure why I can't make it work.

When I try and find the object, or add it to my `uses`, I cannot find it.

The main objective is to use a `.bpl` and invoke it. There are things you can do in the IDE, I guess, to add or link files together, but not sure if that is working since it can't be called in the code as shown below.

```pascal
unit Home;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    dialog   : TFindDialog; //<---
    myDBForm : TDBForm;  // undeclared identifier 'DBForm'
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HandlePack: HModule;
begin
  HandlePack := LoadPackage('L:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\PKG_FORM\DB_Form_PKG.bpl');
  Label1.Caption := 'LoadedPackage';

  if HandlePack > 0 then
  begin

    // don't really want a dialog...  want to load my special .bpl form
    // not sure how... missing how to add the .bpl to my uses
    // how do you add it to the uses statement?
    dialog := TFindDialog.Create(Application);

    // myDBForm := TDBForm.Create(Application);  <-- would rather use this form but it wont work

    if Assigned (dialog) then //<--- same as above... if I can use my form replace here
    begin
      if dialog.Execute then   //<--- same again replace with DBForm once it works.
      try

      finally

      end;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage ('Form class not found');
    UnloadPackage (HandlePack);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage ('Package not found');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //dialog.Free;
  Application.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

```pascal
unit DBForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Comment: Is the `DBForm` unit part of your application source, or does it belong to a separate package project?  If the former, just add `DBForm` to the `uses` clause in the interface section.  If the latter, you must install the package if you mean to use it as a design-time package.  Do you know how to do that?  Is your intention to load the package dynamically, as a run-time package?  Do you know what the difference is? It's really not clear what you're trying to do, what you've tried, or what errors you received.  The code is obviously wrong, but it's not clear what your objective is.

Comment: You can't add a `BPL` file to a `uses` clause, only units. But you can configure the project to statically link to your BPL so it will resolve your unit using the BPL, then you don't need `LoadPackage()`. But if you do use `LoadPackage()`, then you will likely have to use `Classes.(Find|Get)Class()` instead of linking to the unit statically, eg: `var myDBForm: TForm; myDBForm := TFormClass(GetClass('TDBForm')).Create(Application);`. Have you read the documentation yet? [Working with Packages and Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_Packages_and_Components_Index)

Comment: The DBForm is in a separate package project. How do I add that package to the other application?


Classes.(Find|Get)Class() instead of linking to the unit statically, eg: 

var myDBForm: TForm; myDBForm := TFormClass(GetClass('TDBForm')).Create(Application);

I have been reading but it still is a bit confusing. I will look at this doc site you attached.

Comment: The objective was to get one app to use the other... however that is possible.

Comment: And you're sure that runtime packages is the solution?  This was a strategy that came from the days of sneakernet, floppy disks, and space constraints that made it desirable to modularize deployments of reused code instead of compiling them into every application.  It complicates deployment, so I can't imagine many defensible use cases for this today.

Comment: If you have the source for both projects and they're both under your control I would probably prefer keeping it all in source control and linking the "DBForm" application code as a child repo of this application.  Otherwise, build the package and install it.  Remy's link should help.

Comment: The purpose of this is a test only, there was a legacy program I was handed that uses delphi and has a bug with a .pbl missing or not connected correctly to the program. I wanted to first make a demo program that uses a .pbl... then break it, to simulate the bug. Then i would have at least a basic understanding of how to fix it. That is what drove my inquiry.